# I am looking for a Lua find and replace logic

Tags: lua

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP3fZ.png)

I just started working on lua scripting since a week. I have a lua file where in the logic needs to be written for a certain condition.

The condition when gets triggered
it  does an iteration on one of the fields to change value from
(ABC123-XYZ) to this value
(ABC123#1-XYZ) and it keeps increasing whenever iterations happens (ABC123#2-XYZ)

I need to run a function that removes the # followed by number to change it back to (ABC123-XYZ). Looking for any advice!

Edit 1:
Below is the updated code that is written Thanks to @Piglet

I have another scenario if therr are two hashes in the variable.

```
local x = 'BUS144611111-PNB_00#80901#1555-122TRNHUBUS' 
local b = x:gsub("#%d+","")

function remove_char(a) a=a:gsub("#%d+","") 
return a; 
end if string.match(x,"#")
then print('function') 
print(remove_char(x)); 
else print(x); 
end
```

Expected output should be
x = 'BUS144611111-PNB_00#80901-122TRNHUBUS' for the aforesaid variable

Comment: Do you have any code from your attempts to solve this problem you can add to your question? This is both good to show you have put in the same effort you are asking us to, and to help us to refine our answer to your level of understanding.

Comment: Do not include images of code, it is much better to include the code as text in your post. you can use code fences \``` or 4 spaces before each line of the code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local a = "ABC123#1-XYZ"

local b = a:gsub("#%d+", "")
```

this will remove any `#` followed by or one more digits from your string.

Comment: This worked.. Many Thanks.. I have to modify this bit to add another  scenario when there are multiple # in the variable. 

`local x = 'BUS144611111-PNB_0080901#1555-122TRNHUBUS'
local b = x:gsub("#%d+","")

function remove_char(a)
    a=a:gsub("#%d+","")
    return a;
end
if string.match(x,"#") then
    print('function')
    print(remove_char(x));

else 
    print(x);
end`